# How to fetch OS environment variable for class level annotation @PropertySource in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to use ENV variable in a string value, which is then to be supplied to `@PropertySource` class level annotation. But this doesn't work, the `String` value is passed as it is:

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = "./#{systemEnvironment['SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT']}/${spring.profiles.active}.properties")

    public class ApplicationSecretProperties {
                  ...
        }
```

Also, many answers suggested to use `System.getenv("SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT")`, using that the following error occurs at compile time:

```
The value for annotation attribute PropertySource.value must be a constant expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure SpEL is valid for that annotation (the JavaDocs don't say one way or another). But the [OS environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) is already bound into the Spring environment for you. Have you tried:

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:./${SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT}/${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

You probably also want to use `file:` prefix to be explicit about how to find the file.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, it works when I set the environment variable in the IDE, but doesn't run in the actual scenario.

Comment: @ankitMISHRA check if the env is accessible to the user

Comment: It should also work from command line or anywhere else, not just IDE. Make sure where ever you start the process (command line, etc) has the variable set.